# Quick woocommerce PHP advice. Where is the data?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I am trying to edit some of our wordpress, woocommerce data for a client and our PHP programmer is out of action so it falls on me. I am not a PHP programmer and pretty new to woocommerce too. I think I have narrowed the data I need to alter to this loop:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?> 

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I think the "content" and "product" data is what I need to edit. My question is, where is this data stored? It calls "get_Template_part" and retrieves that data to display it, but where is it? And for clarification, I am not looking to alter the product metadata but the structure and layout of the post itself. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to ask your PHP programmer for the Wordpress login details. Then you can edit the woocommerce products etc.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, I don't mean the meta data, like the price and description, I need the structure of the post so I can alter the look of it.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive of what you want to do. For example do you want to restructure the layout of the shop product page? Or do you want to change the size of the product image, text or something similar to that?

Comment: Specifically I need to reorder the pricing structure of each post on the shop page. I was able to do the single products page by altering the price.php file so I assume there is something similar for the shop page posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content should be located in your theme directory in a folder called `woocommerce` assuming the programmer made the appropriate overrides. If not, you need to make a woocommerce folder and put the contents of `plugins/woocommerce/templates` in there. See [Template Structure + overriding templates via a theme](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) by Woo.

**The file should be `content-product.php`.**

See [Github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/templates) for a master WooCommerce template structure. You might also be working on an older WooCommerce install.

You can restructure using overrides on the hooks referenced in the `plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-hooks.php` file using your `functions.php` file or here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/.